# MVC: Update a record of a View table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, join, sql-update

I have a view joining multiple tables. I am able to set one of the columns of the view as a primary so that It appears like a table. Now I wish to update one of the tables included in the View's join but I get the error `View or function 'XXX' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.`

my update is like

```
Persons P = Personrepository.getPerson(256)
p.Active = 0;
Personrepository.Update(p);
Personrepository.save();
```

After the the update I return the results of the View again. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trigger on the view. You would create an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on the view. There's an example in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx